# Xamarin Forms - Azure login page returns not found?

Tags: android, azure, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to enable my users to authenticate on Azure AD. 
I have registered my app on Azure mobile center, enabled indentity and took note of the Azure auth endpoint.

I also registered my app in the Azure AD app registration as a native app.

I finally went back to my Mobile center to enable Azure AD indentity, set the client ID to be the same as the Azure application ID.

I guess things are not clear enough here for me.

I think that my implementation of the authentication in Xamarin is OK because when I click on my button on my Android project

```
private async void LoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (App.Authenticator != null)
                authenticated = await App.Authenticator.AuthenticateAsync();
            }
        }
```

A new window, with the "Authenticate" title, appears. However, I can't get to my endpoint and get the message :

> The webpage
>   https://mobile-{someNumbers}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad might
>   be temporarly down or it may have been moved permanently to a new web
>   address

My authentication method is the most basic one, from a sample :

```
 public async Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync()
        {
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = await AuthenticationManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Authenticated !");
                    }
                }
                success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return success;
        }
    }
```

Has anyone met this issue before ?
Any pointers on how to be able to log in to the AD services ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you could leverage the server-flow authentication to test that you have all the settings correct. Browser at `https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad` and find that whether you could get the successful authentication page. For more detailed tutorials about AAD authentication for Azure Mobile Apps, you could refer to Adrian Hall's blog [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/enterprise/). Additionally, for Client-managed and Server-managed authentication for Mobile Apps, you could follow this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#a-nameauthenticationaauthenticate-users).

Comment: It was a configuration issue indeed.
My homepage URL was not set to the right path.
Thank you !